# How to align the inside box to center of the table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have the table, inside the table I have another box , I am struggling to align the box in center of the table.

My CSS code is

Inside box code

```
.inside_box{
border: medium solid;
display: table-cell;
float: none;
font-family: Helvetica-bold;
font-size: 20.19px;
height: 100px;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 300px;
}
```

Outside table CSS:

```
.outer_table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #1A6DAC;    
    font-size: 24px;
    left: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    width: 740px;
}
```

[image]

How to align the inside box in center?

Comment: Can we have your relevant HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your HTML is something like this

```
<div class="outer_table">
    <div class="inside_box">hello world</div>
</div>
```

So, you are using `display: table-cell;` for `.inside_box` and `margin: auto;` won't work, as it's a table cell now, so what you can do is, wrap a `div` around *hello world* text, like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zDXtA/)

```
<div class="outer_table">
    <div class="inside_box"><div>hello world</div></div>
</div>
```

And use CSS like

```
.inside_box {
    border: medium solid;
    display: table;
    font-family: Helvetica-bold;
    font-size: 20.19px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
.outer_table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #1A6DAC;
    font-size: 24px;
    left: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    width: 740px;
}

.inside_box > div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Make sure you port the `text-align: center;` and `vertical-align: middle;` properties from `.inside_box` to `.inside_box > div` selector block.

---

> Note: You won't need `float: none;`, not sure why you are using that.

---

As I got a comment, that what if you do not want to add an extra `div` element, so think like that you are using `td` without a `table` tag. So there is no way for that `div` with `display: table-cell;` to respect `margin: auto;`.

[From Mozilla Developer Network :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

[image]

Comment: And what if the OP can't add the extra `div`?

Comment: @Vucko You cannot apply `margin` anyways, so the other way to do this is to use `position: absolute;` which I won't prefer cuz `vertical-align` won't work

Comment: I also don't prefer using `position:absolute` for centering but it is also a "workable" solution. I would mention that also in you answer.

Comment: @Vucko No, that's what comments are for :) also, as I specified, `vertical-align` won't work if `position: absolute;` is used

Comment: The `height` is specified so you can use `line-height` instead of `vertical-align`. Nevertheless, +1 :)

Comment: @Vucko Thank you but again, no, as am not sure whether OP will be having a single line, or double? because he is using *hello world*, so If more than 1 line, than `line-height` will be a dirty solution yea? :)

Comment: I agree :) the OP needs to specify his question better to avoid discussions like this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change and make your css like this:

```
.outer_table td {
text-align: center; // Align center
}

.inside_box {
float: none; // if you set float left or right your box will move right there
margin: 0px auto; // this setting for balancing margin left and right
}



<table class="outer_table">
<tr><td><div class="inside_box">Hellow wolrd!</div></td></tr>
</table>
```